# Is there any SQL query Parser for hive?

Tags: sql, parsing, hive, hiveql

I have a very complex query with multiple clauses like "group by", "order by", subqueries, etc. Is there any Hive SQL parser which I can use to capture these tokens from the query. I could not find any proper library to achieve this. Suggestions are appreciated thanks!

Comment: Hive accepts SQL queries.  What issue are you having?

Comment: I know that and I already have a SQL query, But I want to tokenize it and extract for an eg group by columns, how would I extract that?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [tobymao/sqlglot](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot), specifically the section on [#Metadata](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot#metadata)

---

For example,

```
from sqlglot import parse_one, exp
for gb in parse_one("SELECT foo, count(bar) FROM baz GROUP BY foo").find_all(exp.Group):
  print(gb)
```

prints

> GROUP BY foo

Comment: Its printing the table name perfectly. But it is not printing the database name. For eg if the query is "select ff from db.tb", it would return only tb. It will miss database db.

Comment: @Asrinivas, the object model does contain the database. `parse_one("select ff from db.tb").find_all(exp.From)` will return a generator of objects. They are of type sqlglot.expressions.Table, and they contain the database, if it was specified.

`for from_clause in parse_one("select ff from db.tb").find_all(exp.From):
    print(from_clause)
`
>> FROM db.tb

Answer (score 1):

You can try the "general sql parser" http://www.sqlparser.com, which is available for multiple languages,  or  Uber's open sourced query parser https://eng.uber.com/queryparser/, which is in Haskell. Just doing some experiments and find which works better.